# Upload & Download functionality via API (PHP)

Tags: php, api, upload, download

I want to develop a simple web-site with upload & download functionality. From what I've already read on the internet it seems that letting users upload/download files to/from your server may be really dangerous (I am aware of uploading to non-public folder, but still). Is there any web-site providing API for that purpose, or is there any way to ensure that the files uploaded to your server won't blow up one day?!?

Note: I am programming in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long you make sure they're non-executable and don't clogger up your storage or bandwidth you'll be fine.

You may be able to use the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) with your site, but I think it's overly complicated way to bring new problems while solving only some of your old ones.

Comment: What do you mean by **non-executable**? Like file rights? Downloading a file means to read it, as far as I understand. So, **uploaded files will have a right to be read by the server**. Is that it? Or you mean something related to the extensions (which can be easily faked)?

Comment: If you are using a Unix based system (which I assumed) you may modify file permissions to not execute (run) any code. This is a permission separated from read or write. Otherwise you'll just have to make sure files never are executed as a script.

Comment: Will it work in PHP ? Please see this also: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/core